# What is the best way to link two ARM template in Azure

Tags: json, linux, azure, azure-hdinsight, azure-vm-templates

1. HDI cluster on template2:-

> ```
> template.json
> parameters.sjon
> deploy.sh
> ```

2. Azure VM on template1:-

> ```
> template.json
> parameters.sjon
> deploy.sh
> ```

I am able to deploy 1 and 2 separately without any issues.

3. Now I want to get the HDI cluster headnode IP and use in property file on Azure VM.

How can I achieve 3 and deploy 1,2,3 in an order at one go?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your scenario, you could use the following steps.

1.Deploy template 2.

2.After template 2 deploy successful, get parameters you want from HDI cluster and pass parameters to template 1.

3.Deploy template 1.

Note: If you want to use this way, your template should have different name.

Comment: How can accomplish step2 here? How can I get parameters from HDI cluster and pass to template1? Already I have parameters for template1 to pass.

Comment: You could use `shell` to control. Use `shell function`.

Answer (score 1):

Just merge those templates into one, make Azure VM depend on the HD cluster and pass in the IP from the cluster to the VM extension using something like this:

```
 "[reference('mastervmid','2016-09-01').ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress]"
```

Comment: What do you mean by merge? Do you have any example?

Comment: well, merge content from one template into the other

Comment: Do you have any example for merging templates?

Comment: What I have replace in above reference syntax instead of mastervmid?

Comment: why are you asking, there's an answer in this thread already @karan

Comment: Instead of shell script, I want to try using merge ARM template?

Comment: Do you have any examples?

Comment: I am trying to Private IP of HDI cluster. I think script says mentions Azure VM. Can you tell for HDI cluster?

Comment: Kindly reply for my above question

Comment: I am stuck with this. Can you help me